# jquery tabs that when minimised overflow on the right to a drop down menu

Tags: jquery

I've been asked to provide a jquery tabs solution for a lot of tabs, more than will ever fit into a browser window. What's been suggested is that as the tabs are hidden on the right they overflow into a drop down menu making them available without making the tabs two line or scrolling to reveal the hidden tabs. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI provides plugin for tabs functionality. Have a look at the link

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: I know about that plugin but wanted something a little out of the ordinary. Tabs that literally flow into a drop down if there is too many tabs to display in the given screen with, 100 percent layout with loads and loads of tabs.